# Is it a good practice to have dependencies in the following manner in a Java application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop

I have observed this pattern a lot in a springboot mircoservice that I now should act as the owner of.
There is a DAO class, "A", a service class "B" that does some business logic and requires a reference of "A" to be instantiated.

There is another service class that requires both "B" and "A" in order to be instantiated.

The application works as intended, but I still do not feel as though this is the best approach that can be taken.

Should I just add wrapper methods in "B" for the DB operations of "A" so that "B" can effectively replace all usages of "A" ?

Is there a better approach to follow in these cases?

Comment: Non business logic related operations of "A"? Is there business logic in DAO classes?

Comment: No, business logic is limited only to B. 
A has only straightforward DB operations, like find(), save().

Edited question to remove this ambiguity.

Comment: You could combine C and B into a single service. It's not a good idea to expose DAO methods in a service though, that just breaks abstraction and for what...avoiding injecting a DAO that you need? You could also see about adding a facade layer that calls the services, and have the services only call DAOs, but that's likely to require more refactoring and might not be a valid solution.

Comment: Based on the limited description here, it doesn't sound like a problem.